# Everytime I run the code it always appear as an infinite loop,why?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int okay;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:"); //allows user to enter a number
        okay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Multiplication(okay); //takes the user input and shows the table for that number
    }
    static void Multiplication(int number)
    {
        int value = 10;
        for (int row = 2; row <= value;) 
        {
            for (int column = 2; column <= value; ++column) 
            {
                Console.Write("{0, 4}", number * column); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

}
Everytime I run the code it always appear as an infinite loop,why?
Im not sure what else to do

Comment: I want it to display the multiplication table only once

Comment: Take a look to my post below. I have implemented the whole scenario.

Comment: You're not increasing `row`.

Answer (score 4):

`for (int row = 2; row <= value;)`

You're not incrementing `row`, so of course it never exits the loop.

This type of error is trivial to diagnose on your own by setting breakpoints and using a debugger.

Comment: `This type of error is trivial` - yes, and it should have been closed as a typo/unable to reproduce, not answered

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not incrementing row anywhere so it is an infinite loop.

```
for (int row = 2; row <= value;row++)
```

will solve the problem. You can also increment row with greater number if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Update condition for the `outer loop` is missing; you have to increment the `row` by `1` in the update condition. hence your loop will be like the following:

```
for (int row = 2; row <= value;row ++) 
        {
            // statemets
        }
```

Few more suggestions:

The Don't expect all input by the user are convertable to an integer, there may be chances of getting string as input. if you ware using `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` for conversion, definitely exception will be thrown if conversion failed. So i suggest you to use [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) for conversion.

Then If your requirement is to print the multiplication table of the given number you need not to use double for loop. you can handle them in a single loop.

So the complete scenario according to my suggestion will be as follows:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int okay;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out okay))
        {
            Multiplication(okay);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void Multiplication(int number)
    {
        int value = 10;
        for (int mult = 2; mult <= value; mult++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2} \n", number, mult, number * mult);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should increment the value of the `row`.

```
for (int row = 2; row <= value; row++) 
        {
            for (int column = 2; column <= value; ++column) 
            {
                Console.Write("{0, 4}", number * column); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
```

Comment: What would be the expected output for this ?` Console.Write("{0, 4}", number * column); `